# Django add model instance data to widget in forms.py

Tags: python, django-models, django-views, django-forms, instance

forms.py

```
from django.forms import *
from .models import client, notes, contractor, cNotes, personnel, pNotes, estimate, job

class clientForm(self, ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = client
        fields = ("contractor", "firstName", "lastName", "phoneNumber", "email", "gateCode")
        #inst = client.objects.get(pk=pk)
        widgets = {
          'firstName': TextInput(attrs={'value' : self.instance.firstName}), 'lastName': TextInput(attrs={'value' : self.instance.lastName})
      }
```

`self.instance.firstName` Needs to fetch the current first name of that instance in the model so the value of the widget when the edit form view is open is the current value (Note: setting `initial=` doesn't work for what I want). I have tried many Solutions but I can't seem to get any of them to work.

Edit: I tried overriding init

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['firstName'].widget.attrs.update(
            {'value': self.instance.firstName},
        )
```

but when I do this it says self is not defined.

Edit: I also tried passing the instance data by getting it in the view and passing it to the form by overriding `get_form_kwargs`

models.py

```
class client(models.Model):
    #model representing client
    contractor = models.ForeignKey('contractor', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text='Enter first name of client', null=True, blank=True)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text='Enter last name of client', null=True, blank=True)
    phoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=16, help_text='Enter number for client', null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, help_text='Enter email for client', blank=True, null=True)
    gateCode = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text='Enter gate code for client', blank=True, null=True)
    fullName = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text='', blank=True, null=True)
    client_id = models.SlugField(max_length=50, help_text='', primary_key=True)
    initialContactDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py

```
def eClientF(request, pk=None):
    inst = client.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        client_form = clientForm(request.POST, instance=inst)
        estimate_form = estimateForm(request.POST, instance=inst)
        notes_form = notesForm(request.POST, instance=inst)
        if(client_form.is_valid() and estimate_form.is_valid() and notes_form.is_valid()):
            cli = client_form.save()
            estimate2 = estimate_form.save(False)
            notes2 = notes_form.save(False)
            estimate2.client = cli
            notes2.client = cli
            estimate2.save()
            notes2.save()
            return redirect('/main/client')
    else:
        client_form = clientForm(instance=inst)
        estimate_form = estimateForm(instance=inst)
        notes_form = notesForm(instance=inst)
    args = {}
    args["client_form"] = client_form
    args["estimate_form"] = estimate_form
    args["notes_form"] = notes_form
    return render(request, "main/eClformTemp.html", args)
```

models.py and views.py have been reduced to relevant code only

Edit: I have modified views.py as suggested, but when I try using this form it doesn't load the page and says self is not recognized referring to froms.py where it says `TextInput(attrs={'value' : self.instance.firstName})`

Edit:
It won't though, I know when you past instance when creating the form in views it should populate but it doesn't. I have referenced the docs and many examples to confirm I was doing it correctly and I was but it wasn't working. To work around it I ran the server and opened the form then I inspected element and copied the html and manually added value to the html and used what I copied as the template to ensure this workaround will work. However the template cannot be manually made because it wouldn't properly reflect changes in the database. I just need to know how I can pass the current model instance into the widget attrs for value. Ik I will have to edit init and update the widget that way but my implementation wouldn't work so I'm asking how to do it correctly.

Comment: Could you please show us your models.py and your views.py?

Comment: @amadousow They are posted now.

Comment: i think the problem is in your views.py look at carefully your indentation  you should have an else for request.method=='get' to pass inside there the form and the instance.

Comment: and inside your else for request.method=='get' you put this one there client_form = clientForm(instance=inst) estimate_form = estimateForm(instance=inst).and in your args you do something like this         args = {}
        args["client_form"] = client_form
        args["estimate_form"] = estimate_form ...

Comment: I updated views.py to fix it. It just got junked up from me trying to solve my issue. Now that my views.py is in order how can I access the clientFn arg in my forms.py? And thx for the help!

Comment: Try to change this args["client_form"] = clientForm
    args["estimate_form"] = estimateForm
    args["notes_form"] = notesForm
    args["clientFn"] = inst.firstName
    args["clientLn"] = inst.lastName to args["client_form"] = client_form
    args["estimate_form"] = estimate_form
    args["notes_form"] = notes_form

Comment: and after you can return render(request,"your template",args)

Comment: I have made those changes but I am still facing the same error

Comment: @amadousow how can I now use that instance in forms.py. currently it says "self" isn't defined.

Comment: Try this : from django.forms import *
from .models import client, notes, contractor, cNotes, personnel, pNotes, estimate, job

class clientForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = client
        fields = ("contractor", "firstName", "lastName", "phoneNumber", "email", "gateCode")

Comment: Don't overrid init and don't put any self there.try to write exactly what i wrote above with indentation ,you don't need widgets for that.if the data exists in database then in your views.py it will populate it automatically

Comment: Please check edit. Thanks for helping!